# Error "was not declared in the scope"

Tags: c++, struct

Este error me surge en la primera linea;

> "Algo was not declared in this scope".

Se que es un error muy básico, pero no me estoy dando cuenta en qué estoy fallando y por qué.

Este es mi código:

```
void funcion(Algo x){
    x.b= 1 ;
}

int main(){
    struct Algo{
        int b;
    };
    Algo x;
    funcion(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscas algo así ?

```
typedef struct {
int b;
} Algo;
void funcion(Algo x){
x.b= 1 ;
}
int main() {
Algo x;
funcion(x);
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias! era justamente eso.